# Basic function pointer misunderstanding

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int fun1 (int);
int fun2 (int);
int fun3 (int);

int (*fun4) (int) = fun1; // 1

void main()
{
    int (*fun4) (int) = fun2; // 2
    printf ("%d\n", fun4(3));
    printf ("%d\n", fun3(3));
    getch();
}

int fun1 (int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

int fun2 (int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int fun3 (int x)
{
    return fun4(x);
}
```

It yields the output:

```
6
4
```

I'm not sure why that happens.

At the line where //2 is written, we defined that fun4 points to fun2. so from then on, when i write fun4(x) its the same as writing fun2(x). I'm not sure why the second print yields 4.

Could anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: There are two different fun4's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so from then on, when i write fun4(x) its the same as writing fun2(x). I'm not sure why the second print yields 4.

No.

```
int (*fun4) (int) = fun2; // 2
```

is visible inside the `main` scope only. `fun4` is pointer to `fun2` only inside the `main`. Outside of `main`'s scope `fun4` is pointer to `fun1`.
When you call `fun4(x)` in `fun3` then it is equivalent to `fun1(x)`

Comment: Ah I see. so if i have another procedure outside of main that uses fun4, it will be equivalent to fun1?

Answer (score 1):

In your example `fun3` calls `fun4` and the definition of `fun3` does not know anything about the local `fun4` variable. To make it clear, the assignment `fun2 = fun4` is a pointer assignment, not name assignment. When you call this function it will not search it by name, but only by pointer, and the pointer assigned is the one that points to `fun1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two definition of `fun4` one is local and another one is global.
If we replace definition of `fun4` your code look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int fun1 (int);
int fun2 (int);
int fun3 (int);

int (*fun4) (int) = fun1; // 1 (global definition)

void main()
{
    int (*fun4) (int) = fun2; // 2 (local definition)
    printf ("%d\n", fun2(3)); //! Since fun4(local) pointing to fun2
    printf ("%d\n", fun3(3));
    getch();
}

int fun1 (int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

int fun2 (int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int fun3 (int x)
{
    return fun1(x); //! Since fun4(global) pointing to fun1
}
```

**Note:** Please refer to the comments for the changes

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code like this:

```
int (*fun4) (int) = fun1; // 1

void main()
{
    fun4 = fun2; // 2
    printf ("%d\n", fun4(3));
    printf ("%d\n", fun3(3));
    getch();
}
```

Then it will behave as you expected. The change is on the line marked `// 2`. Instead of declaring a different variable called `fun4` at local scope, it will assign a different value to the existing global `fun4`.